# how can i append a new <td> to nth <tr> using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

im trying to create a tic-tac-toe board dynamically using a nested loop, i got this much:

```
    //fill grid using jquery
for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {

        //add a row
    $("#grid").append("<tr>");

        //3 rows, 3 columns 
    for ( var j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++ ) {

            //write cell
        $("#grid").append("<td>").data("id", i * 3 + j );
    }
}
```

however this generates the following html:

```
<table id="grid">

    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

</table>
```

how can i append the `<td>`s so that they get added to the correct `<tr>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the cells to the row, not directly to the table:

```
//fill grid using jquery
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  //add a row
  var row = $("<tr>");
  $("#grid").append(row);

  //3 rows, 3 columns 
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

    //write cell
    var cell = $("<td>").data("id", i * 3 + j);
    row.append(cell);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it in two ways

First just an edit in your code.

```
 for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {

            //add a row
        $("#grid").append("<tr>");

            //3 rows, 3 columns 
        for ( var j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++ ) {

           var td = $("<td>").data("id", i * 3 + j );
            $("#grid"),find("tr:eq("+i+")").append(td);
        }
    }
```

Second, use a variable to store your TR

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {

        //create row and store that in variable
    var tr = $('<tr>');


    for ( var j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++ ) {


        tr.append("<td>").data("id", i * 3 + j );
    }

    $('#grid').append(tr);
}
```

Comment: That will set the data to the row instead of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a try.

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {

        //add a row
    var tr = $('<tr>');

        //3 rows, 3 columns 
    for ( var j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++ ) {

        td = $('<td>');
        td.text(((i*3) + j) + 1);

            //write cell
        tr.append(td);
    }

    $('#grid').append(tr);
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6SU86/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var html='';
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        html += '<td data-id=' + i * 3 + j + '></td>'
    }
    $("#grid").append("<tr>" + html + "</tr>");
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a7dZn/)**

Produces:

```
<table id="grid">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-id="00"></td>
            <td data-id="01"></td>
            <td data-id="02"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-id="30"></td>
            <td data-id="31"></td>
            <td data-id="32"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-id="60"></td>
            <td data-id="61"></td>
            <td data-id="62"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```